# ImageAdapter No Enclosing Error

Tags: java, android, gridview, scope

I'm currently working on an application to allow the user to select an ImageView from a GridView gallery and display it on its own and in all its beauty.

The GridView is on a fragment and then will pass the data to an activity to show the selected image. My entire project is working up until initialising the ImageAdapter. I receive an error stating that there is no enclosing instance of type GalleryView. I have tried and tried and then tried some more, was reluctant to post the question but I'm still no closer to resolving the issue.

```
public class SingleImageGallery extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_image_view);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.SingleView);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.pics[position]);
  }
}
```

Comment: @laalto the ImageAdapter is indeed a nested class in GalleryView, I have since removed it from the GalleryView class and everything is working perfectly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that you're attempting to instantiate a non-static inner class without a reference to the containing outer class.

I'm guessing your `ImageAdapter` is a non-static inner class in `GalleryView`. You should probably make `ImageAdapter` `static` as it should not need a reference to `GalleryView`.